# Unity not adding reference to managed assembly when it's not marked as for all platforms

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, assembly-references

I have a Unity native plugin with next structure:

- `Plugins/Android/Foo.jar` // Native Android library
- `Plugins/Android/Foo.Android.dll` // Managed Unity wrapper to let access native Android routine (Marked as for Android only)
- `Plugins/iOS/libFoo.a` // Native iOS library
- `Plugins/iOS/Foo.iOS.dll` // Managed Unity wrapper to let access native iOS routine (Marked as for iOS only)

When I select Android or iOS platform and open my Unity project in MonoDevelop it not add reference for Foo.Android.dll. The same situation for iOS.
Also `Unity Editor Console` contains error about not referenced classes used in my Unity code outside Plugin.

`Assets/MainScript.cs(3,11): error CS0234: The type or namespace name`Bar' does not exist in the namespace `Foo'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

When change `Foo.iOS.dll`/`Foo.Android.dll` platform setting to `Any Platform` before opening MonoDevelop under iOS/Android respectively it's works as expected.

When I build project it's built successfully both for iOS and Android.

Where I need place my managed libraries or which settings I should use to force Unity add appropriate libraries as reference in opening MonoDevelop project?

Unity Editor 5.2.0f3, OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F27)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution:

Unity Editor include only libraries marked as for `Editor` than problem solved adding new stub library in `Plugins\X86\Foo.Editor.dll` with only `Editor` target platform selected.

After this Unity add reference to stub `Plugins\X86\Foo.Editor.dll` in opening Mono Develop project but use actual platform-dependent libraries when built.